# Developing with libpcsclite error compiling (undefined)

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

Im trying to test a sample PCSC application on Linux that I've seen on the web http://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.com.es/2010/04/pcsc-sample-in-c.html

This application use libpsclite library that I installed with apptitude install libpcsclite-dev.

Why I get references undefined error when compile it?

gcc -I/usr/include/PCSC -lpcsclite sample.c -o sample/tmp/ccY4bNdm.o: En la función `main':
sample.c:(.text+0x9b): referencia a`SCardEstablishContext' sin definir
sample.c:(.text+0xb2): referencia a `pcsc_stringify_error' sin definir
sample.c:(.text+0xf8): referencia a`SCardListReaders' sin definir
sample.c:(.text+0x10f): referencia a `pcsc_stringify_error' sin definir
sample.c:(.text+0x171): referencia a`SCardConnect' sin definir
sample.c:(.text+0x188): referencia a `pcsc_stringify_error' sin definir
sample.c:(.text+0x1b7): referencia a`g_rgSCardT0Pci' sin definir
sample.c:(.text+0x1bd): referencia a `g_rgSCardT0Pci' sin definir
sample.c:(.text+0x1cc): referencia a`g_rgSCardT1Pci' sin definir
sample.c:(.text+0x1d2): referencia a `g_rgSCardT1Pci' sin definir
sample.c:(.text+0x21f): referencia a`SCardTransmit' sin definir
sample.c:(.text+0x236): referencia a `pcsc_stringify_error' sin definir
sample.c:(.text+0x2e5): referencia a`SCardTransmit' sin definir
sample.c:(.text+0x2fc): referencia a `pcsc_stringify_error' sin definir
sample.c:(.text+0x37b): referencia a`SCardDisconnect' sin definir
sample.c:(.text+0x392): referencia a `pcsc_stringify_error' sin definir
sample.c:(.text+0x3c0): referencia a`SCardFreeMemory' sin definir
sample.c:(.text+0x3d7): referencia a `pcsc_stringify_error' sin definir
sample.c:(.text+0x3fa): referencia a`SCardReleaseContext' sin definir
sample.c:(.text+0x411): referencia a `pcsc_stringify_error' sin definir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Thanks for any help received!!

Comment: Did you try to put `-lpcsclite` at the rightmost end of your compilation command line?

Comment: Thats right!!! With that compilation works! And I waste pretty time doing fool. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for reference. It seems that the makefile that is provided in that link is broken (at least for me). This is a working makefile for me:

```
# Linux
PCSC_CFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --cflags libpcsclite)
LDLIBS := $(shell pkg-config --libs libpcsclite)

# Mac OS X
#PCSC_CFLAGS := -framework PCSC

CFLAGS += $(PCSC_CFLAGS)

sample: sample.c

clean:
    rm -f sample
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Just change `LDFLAGS` to `LDLIBS`

Comment: eL magnifeco! Danke

Answer (score -2):

If you can't compile with your makefile, you've to reinstall some libraries; for me these steps work fine.

## update

> sudo apt-get update

## install PC/CS CommonAccessCard

> sudo apt-get install libpcsclite1 pcscd pcsc-tools

## verify if smartcard reader is recognized

> pcsc_scan

## install  /usr/include/PCSC  -   for dev. PCSC - Linux

PC/SC driver for ACS USB CCID smart card readers
Middleware to access a mart card using PC/SC (development files)

And try again.